# The Ising approximation - what exactly is it?

Tags: solid-state-physics, terminology, ising-model, spin-models, ferromagnetism

I am slightly confused about the nature of the Ising model to study ferromagnetism. Consider the Heisenberg Hamiltonian with Zeeman term:
\[H=-\frac{1}{2} \sum_{i\ne j}J_{ij} S_i\cdot S_j+g\mu_B {B}\sum_iS_i^z\]
This can also be written as:
\[H=-\frac{1}{2} \sum_{i\ne j} J_{ij}S_i^z\cdot S_j^z+g\mu_B {B}\sum_iS_i^z-\frac{1}{2} \sum_{i\ne j} J_{ij}S_i^-S_j^+\]
Ashcroft and Mermin define the [Ising model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ising_model) to be simply the exclusion of the last term in the above expansion. Whilst other sources (e.g. Simon, 2013) say that it is saying the atoms are in spin states $+S$ or $-S$. These do not appear equivalent - not even in mean field approximation where (correct me if I am wrong) the last term vanishes anyway due to rotational symmetry. Thus which is the standard definition and are they linked in any way?

Comment: Hint: Without the last term, you can simply specify each $S^z_i$ when specifying an eigenstate. So call that $\pm S$.

Comment: @AHusain So what happens in this case to all the states, $-S+1$, $-S+2$,...,$S-2$,$S-1$?

Comment: It's +/- 1/2. Just rescaled.